# Manera mas eficiente en VBA y Excel de reemplazar valores en una columna por un solo valor

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript, visual-basic, vbs

estoy haciendo una macro en Excel y necesito cambiar los valores de una columna (un rango unidimensional) por un solo valor, es decir que todos sean 0

Tengo esto:

```
Dim iCell As Range
For Each iCell In Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Cells
    With iCell
        .Value = 1
    End With
Next iCell
```

Este código me funciona mas o menos pero es muy eficiente y me rompe el excel jaja, necesito la manera mas eficiente de hacerlo porque esta de por si no funciona o funciona muy tarde y la columna tiene muchos valores.

Entonces no se si el código tiene algo mal o el código es simplemente ineficiente.

En resumen, convertir todos los valores que haya en esa columnaw en un 1

Answer (score 1):

indagando un poquito mas justo después de hacer la pregunta encontré la forma perfecta.

```
Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Value = 1
```

Es eficiente en muchos aspectos.

Answer (score 0):

Sub ReplaceSpecificValues()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("NOMBREDETUHOJA")

```
For Each cell In ws.Range("A:A")
    If cell.Value = "Valor Antiguo" Then
        cell.Value = "Nuevo Valor"
    End If
Next cell
```

End Sub

Comment: Hola Alejandro, bienvenido y gracias por tu colaboración, las respuestas que son solo código, son consideradas de baja calidad, te sugiero que edites la tuya, y expliques de que forma resuelve el problema planteado, así evitarás que sea cerrada y/o recibir votos negativos. ver [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.